# passport authentication error: Strategy#authenticate must be overridden by subclass

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate and login a user but it show error: Strategy#authenticate must be overridden by subclass, how can i fix this error

What could be the cause?

Passport.js

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport').Strategy

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.use("local",

        new LocalStrategy({usernameField:"email"}, (email, password, done)=>{

            User.findOne({email:email})

                .then(user=>{

                    if(!user){

                        return done(null, false,{message:"That email is not registered"})
                    }

                    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch)=>{

                        if(err) throw err

                        if(isMatch){

                            return done(null, user)

                        }else {

                            return done (null, false,{message:"password incorrect"})

                        }
                    })
                })

                .catch(err=>console.log(err))

        })
    )

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {

        done(null, user.id)

    })

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {

        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {

            done(err, user)
        })
    })
}
```

Login.js

```
const express = require('express');

const passport = require("passport");

const router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */

router.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {

    res.render('login')

})



router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {

        if (err) { return next(err); }

        if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }

        req.logIn(user, function(err) {

            if (err) { return next(err); }

            return res.redirect('/');

        });

    })
(req, res, next);

});



module.exports = router
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const logIn = require('./routes/login')

const flash = require('connect-flash')

const session = require('express-session')

const passport = require("passport");

require('./config/passport')(passport)

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}))

//express session

app.use(session({

    secret:'secret',

    resave: false,

    saveUninitialized: true,

}))

app.use(passport.initialize())

app.use(passport.session())

//flash connect

app.use(flash())

app.use((req, res, next)=>{

    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg')

    res.locals.failure_msg = req.flash('error_msg')

    next()
})

app.use(logIn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when passport fails to instantiate an instance of strategy ,I can't see anything wrong in your code , so I suggest you uninstall passport and install it back again

Comment: can u believe i spend my one week to fix this issue and finally it solved thank u

Comment: user logged in successfully when session not created how can i fix this issue

Comment: the user can't log in successfully if there is no session, passport requires session to be able to serialiaze and deserialaize user

Comment: it not show any error when i enter valid user data.for login

Comment: i use console.log in serialize it show user.id when i login but in browser when i go in application, session storage is empty. it not show any key and value

Comment: I think you should post another question with the new problem you facing, meanwhile if my answer helped solve the previous issue please conceder upvote and accept my answer, also when you post the new question leave me the link here in a comment  and I will be happy to help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62553889/session-not-create-after-login-using-passport-js

Comment: that's link of my question